# ffmpeg rotate 90 on Windows not working

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a video that was shot on an iPhone in portrait mode - when I run ffprobe on it, it shows the following information.

```
ffprobe version 3.4 Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libblur
ay --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --ena
ble-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-z
lib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-l
ibmfx
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2017-01-14 01.19.10.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2017-01-14T07:19:10.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.location.ISO6709: +29.8041-097.1844+107.044/
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone SE
    com.apple.quicktime.software: 10.2
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2017-01-14T01:19:10-0600
  Duration: 00:00:22.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8342 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 8244 kb/s, 29.98 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2017-01-14T07:19:10.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 87 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-01-14T07:19:10.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-01-14T07:19:10.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Stream #0:3(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-01-14T07:19:10.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 2
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 3
```

I want to rotate it and remove the rotation flags so that it will play on media players that don't respect the rotation metadata.

When I run this command:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i %1 -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 22 -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 -vf "transpose=clock" -c:a copy "%new_name%"
```

...instead of the video being rotated 90 degrees clockwise like I want, I get the video rotated 180 degrees. I've tried all the different `transpose=x` values, and I can't seem to get a command line that works.

I have other videos that were shot in landscape mode, but 'upside down' - those have a rotation flag of 180 degrees, and when I just let ffmpeg just 'auto rotate' those, it works great - I'm not sure why that doesn't work for the 90 degree case. When I try to just 'auto rotate' using this command:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i %1 -map_metadata 0 -c:a copy "%new_name%"
```

I get a video file that (when played with Windows Media Player) has no video at all. VLC will play it just fine, but I'd really like it to work with Windows Media Player.

**EDIT:** Here is the output from ffprobe on that same file after it has been auto-rotated:

```
C:\>ffprobe "20170114-073811.mov"
ffprobe version 3.4 Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluay --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enble-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-lib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-ibmfx
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '20170114-073811.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2017-01-14T07:38:11.000000Z
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:03.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6189 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1080x1920, 6090 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-01-14T07:38:11.000000Z
      handler_name    : DataHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 88 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-01-14T07:38:11.000000Z
      handler_name    : DataHandler
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to manually adjust the rotation, you should disable the auto-rotation.

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -noautorotate -i %1
       -vf "transpose=cclock" -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0
       -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 22 -c:a copy "%new_name%"
```

Comment: That seemed like a good answer. I changed my script to add the

-noautorotate 

option. When I did this I get the behavior where the rotated video file won't play with Windows Media Player, which is similar to what I see if I don't specify any rotation options and just let ffmpeg autorotate the file. 

I'm starting to think the issue is a limitation in Windows Media Player. (This is on Windows 7).

Comment: Should not be so. I've processed IPhone 7S videos with autorotate and they do play in WMP on 7. Show the full log of `ffprobe output.mp4`

Comment: Thanks @mulvya - I have edited the question to show the ffprobe output from a converted file.

Comment: This could just a matter of format tagging. WMP may not like `qt`: add `-brand mp42` just before the output filename.

Comment: Does not work for me for players that read the metadata (web browsers in particular). They rotate the video an extra 90 degrees.